# Why does browser network show all javascript reloaded after jQuery .ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

[image]I am using jQuery (v1.11.3) on my site and have noticed that after I use $.ajax to load part of content into the page, both Chrome and Firefox list a whole host of javascripts / css files which it seems to reload into the page

My call is cut down as:

```
ajaxUrl = '/sample/ajaxSavedItems';
xhr = $.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl,
    data: jsonObj,
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
            $('#loadMore').remove();
            $('#loadMore-section').replaceWith(data);
    }
})
```

The routine works and the html returned is just the extract from the backend code with no header - just the bare html required to be inserted.

So the question is, why does the network seem to show that all of the existing javascript and css files (around 42 files in total all included in the main page header) are reloaded by the browser (as this obviously slows down the delay of the inserted section).

Comment: The HTML sent back from the server likely has references to those script and stylesheets.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this browser behaviour (network tab in the console)?

Comment: I added a screen shot - there is no reference to those scripts and stylesheets in the HTML sent back from the server - it is just the plain html (checked via the response window in the console) - no scripts or anything...

Comment: How is the `ajax` call triggered? Do you listen to the click of a `submit` button that is within a `form`?

Comment: Probably the ajax request happens before the scripts and css files are loaded, so thay are shown as being loaded after the request is made.

Comment: No - the ajax call is triggered when someone clicks on a link - for example with <a onclick="showSavedItems(<?=$sectionId?>);return false;" ></a>

All of the scripts and javascripts are definitely already loaded on the page before I click the button

Comment: I just realised in the screenshot you can see all of the javascript and css files are being suffixed by ?_=xxxxx - this might explain it - now if only I could find the server setting adding this to the files....